# Converting floating point number to any base

Tags: python, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

How would i convert a float, represented by a string, to a decimal, base between 2 to 36 in Python, without using Python built ins int and float?
meaning: 
convert_float("234.56", base) --> float, or ("10AB", base) --> float

In case that the float ends in .0, the result should be an integer.

Converting integers to any base seems much less complicated, however I couldn't come up or find any solution for the floats.

Comment: And how would a float be represented in a base other than 10? Such numbers are invariably *integers* instead, and `int('10AB', base)` works just fine..

Comment: @MartijnPieters, 0xff34.1a makes sense to me

Comment: my mistake, i forgot to mention that i can't use int or float in the procedure.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: Why can't you use `int`?

Comment: Internally floats are binary, and there's no theoretical issue with representing them in non-decimal bases. One approach might be finding the decimal point, removing it, converting as an integer and then multiplying by the base to the power of the point location - essentially converting mantissa and exponent separately.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am very new to Python, and I am not sure how to go about mantissa and exponent. My idea was 1) to have an alphabet of the allowed characters and 2) have some kind of a generator which represents fractions and exponents. These are just ideas, i can't really figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Node.js will convert a float to a string with any radix up to 36: `(.995).toString(36)` --> '0.ztipx4bipx'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea was quite good already. To implement it, you would first need a dictionary that can convert strings to integers. Then you'd want to split your string into two, at the decimal point. Then, you could reverse your "before" string and iterate through it, multiplying the integer of the current value with 10 to the current index and adding all these values up.

Then, iterate through your "after" string and multiply the current value with the negative current index, adding the values again.

To put this into code:

```
s2i = {"0": 0,
"1": 1,
"2": 2,
...
"Y": 34,
"Z": 35
}

def convert_float(s, base=10):
    ret = 0
    if "." not in s: bef = s
    else: bef, aft = s.split(".")
    for i in enumerate(reversed(bef)):
        integer = s2i[i[1]]
        if integer >= base: raise ValueError
        ret += base**i[0] * integer
    if "." not in s: return ret
    for i in enumerate(aft):
        integer = s2i[i[1]]
        if integer >= base: raise ValueError
        ret += base**-(i[0] + 1) * integer
    return ret

print convert_float("YF.1G90N", 36)

> 1239.04031674
```